# How to get subquery result in Case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can get `subquery` result into the `CASE` statement.

```
Select * from TestDb T
where T.LevelId IN (CASE T.Data WHEN 7 THEN (Select Data from dbo.Split('5,4',',')) ELSE 0 END)
```

***Desire Output***

For 7 --   2 Rows with ID 5 and 4

Else Matching 1 Row with 0

***Error***

> *Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.*

Comment: Whit is your desired output? It's really hard to help you if we don't know what you are trying to do.

Comment: When used at a scalar expression place, the subquery must return no more then 1 value. Yours returns 2. Choose which one you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try:

```
Select * 
from TestDb T
where T.DATA=7 AND T.LEVELID IN (Select Data from dbo.Split('5,4',','))
    OR ((T.DATA IS NULL OR T.DATA<>7) AND T.LEVELID=0)
```

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE TESTDB (LEVELID INT, DATA INT);
INSERT INTO TESTDB values (4,7);
INSERT INTO TESTDB values (0,6);
INSERT INTO TESTDB values (0,NULL);
INSERT INTO TESTDB values (5,7);
INSERT INTO TESTDB values (6,7);
```

Output:

```
LEVELID DATA
4   7
0   6
0   NULL
5   7
```

Comment: If T.DATA is nullable, NULL check is missing in OR .